# Linq lambda using where

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am still learning lambda and Linq from Microsoft site and trying to write some simple example myself to get a deeper understanding of the cool stuff. The more I learn the more I find that stuff interesting but the learning curve is steep. Once again, I will need some more assistance.

Basically, I have class called item where it has properties NodeID, Weight and Category.

I have also a class called Recipient which represent recipient receiving items.

I have also a 2 dimensional boolean table that shows the interaction of one item against the other. If an item1 with ID NodeID1 is not supposed to have with item2 with ID Node2 then the table[Node1][Node2] should have a value true.

What I am trying to find out is the list of recipients that receive stuff that should not be receiving together, in other word stuff that has value true in the table.

```
public class Recipient
{
    private Dictionary<int,item> _itemsReceivedList=new Dictionary<int,item>(); //itemID
    private int _recipientID;

    public int RecipientID{ get; set; }
    public List<int> getListItemInCategory(int category)
    {
        return _itemsReceivedList.Where(x => x.Value.Category == category).Select(x => x.Value.NodeID).ToList();
    }
}

public class item
{
    public int NodeID { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
}
```

In my main program:

```
 private bool[][]    prohibitedMatrix; //prohibitedMatrix[NodeID1][NodeID2]=true means it is prohibited to have Item NodeID1 and NodeID2 together
 private Dictionary<int,Recipient> recipients = new Dictionary<int,Recipient>();
 private Dictionary<int, item> items = new Dictionary<int,item>();
```

given an item with NodeID1, find recipients that has x in _itemReceivedList so that prohibitedMatrix[x.NodeID][NodeID1]= true

```
recipients.Where(x=>x.Value.getListItemInCategory(items[NodeID].Category) 
           && "The NodeID in listItemInCategory and NodeID1 is not
           true)
          .Select(x=>x.Value.RecipientID)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a one-liner this should work:

```
var result = recipients
    .Values
    .Select(r => new 
        { 
            RecipientID = r.RecipientID,
            Items = r.getListItemInCategory(items[NodeID].Category)
        })
    .Where(ri => ri.Items.Any(i => prohibitedMatrix[i.NodeID][NodeID]))
    .Select(ri => ri.RecipientID);
```

or this:

```
var result = recipients
    .Values
    .Where(r => r
        .getListItemInCategory(items[NodeID].Category)
        .Any(i => prohibitedMatrix[i.NodeID][NodeID]))
    .Select(r => r.RecipientID);
```

However better to introduce some utility functions here and partition this. Or use plain-old `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks bartosz. I forgot using the extension any.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found answer to my own question. I may or may not be correct. Please let me know if I am wrong.

This is what I think:

```
recipients.Where((x,y)=>x.Value.getListItemInCategory(items[NodeID1].Category).Contains(y) && prohibitedMatrix[y][NodeID1]).Select(x=>x.Value.RecipientID).ToList()
```